# How to convert datetime to string in linqtosql?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using linqtosql and inside of linq query, I tried to convert datetime type column to string like 'dd-MM-yy'.
However, I got error as following :

> NotSupportedException: Method
>   'System.String
>   ToString(System.String)' has no
>   supported translation to SQL.

following is my linq query:

```
from ffv in Flo_flowsheet_values
where ffv.Flowsheet_key == 2489
&& ffv.Variable_key == 70010558
&& ffv.Status == 'A'
&& ffv.Column_time >= DateTime.ParseExact("2010-06-13 00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", null)
&& ffv.Column_time <= DateTime.ParseExact("2010-06-13 22:59", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", null)
select new  { 
ColumnTime = ffv.Column_time
,ColumnTimeForXCategory = ffv.Column_time.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yy") ***====> this statement invoke error***
,BTValue = Convert.ToDouble( ffv.Value) }
```

Comment: Why do you need the ToString?

Comment: ColumnTimeForXCategory property is string type to express datetime more readerable way. I want to express ColumnTime column like '13-06-2010'. that is why i used ColumnTimeForXCategory property.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `string.Format` than `ToString()` method to solve your problem.
Like

```
ColumnTimeForXCategory = string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yy}",ffv.Column_time.Value)
```

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this post why I was looking for the same answer. Here is what I eventually discovered I can do from looking at the object properties of the date object.

```
CreatedDateTime = 
   modelChartArea.CreatedDateTime.Month + "/" + 
   modelChartArea.CreatedDateTime.Day + "/" + 
   modelChartArea.CreatedDateTime.Year
```

Answer (score 1):

This maybe late but still....try using .AsEnumerable()...I also somehow stumbled on this problem then I found this:
http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/58/comparing-dates-in-linqpad

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing the `DateTime` strings in the expression itself and the LINQ to SQL provider cannot translate that C# code into equivalent T-SQL code.

Try something like this instead:

```
DateTime start 
    = DateTime.ParseExact(
        "2010-06-13 00:00", 
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime end 
    = DateTime.ParseExact(
        "2010-06-13 22:59", 
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

from ffv in Flo_flowsheet_values
where ffv.Flowsheet_key == 2489
    && ffv.Variable_key == 70010558
    && ffv.Status == 'A'
    && ffv.Column_time >= start
    && ffv.Column_time <= end
select new 
{ 
    ColumnTime = ffv.Column_time,
    ColumnTimeForXCategory = ffv.Column_time.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yy")
    BTValue = Convert.ToDouble( ffv.Value)
};
```

Comment: I want convert datetime type column 'ColumnTime' to string type column 'ColumnTimeForXCategory'. I think you misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you can linq wants to translate what you are doing to sql.
Thats not possible in this case. But you could transform it to a string before your query and then pass the string into the linq expression.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the database do string formatting for the UI.  Parse it on the client side.